# How to remove an <img> tag if no file path has been submitted from database

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a repeater showing articles, where a picture can or cannot be submitted.

It works great, but when a picture is not inserted the `alt` text still shows, but no picture obviously.

```
<article class="newsPic">
           <img src="<%# Eval("picFilePath") %>" width="100%" alt="News Picture"/>
</article>
```

How can I remove the control if no file path has been submitted, if the field is null?

I have found this, but at present I can't see how to wrap an `<img>` tag around it?:

```
<asp:Label ID="MailingAddress" runat="server" 
   Text='<%# Eval("MailingAddress") %>' 
   Visible='<%# !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("MailingAddress") as string) %>'/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you just gave an answer to yourself :)

```
<img src='<%# Eval("picFilePath") %>' style="width:100%" alt="News Picture"
    runat="server" visible='<%# !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("picFilePath") as string) %>' />
```

Comment: Wrapping it in an <img> tag threw me completely. The alt text still shows for some reason though..?

Comment: don't forget runat="server"?

Comment: Thanks guys, but now: The server tag is not well formed. :-(

Comment: Use single quotes around the src instead of double

Comment: sorry, it's late and i've been a bit tired. Thanks @mr.freeze.

Comment: @mr.freeze Cheers! Had to change it round a tad:  Cannot create an object of type 'System.Int32' from its string representation '100%' for the 'Width' property. `style="max-width:100%`"